# Can the terminal calculate combinations?

Tags: command-line

I would like to know if the ubuntu terminal can calculate different combinations (like nCr in math). But I don't want just the number of possible combinations but the combinations themselves.

Update: After more research I found I need not a combination calculator but one that does permutations.

Comment: Combinations of _what_? Please [edit] your question and clarify. Add an example input and the output you would like.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about the coefficients of a [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), the first step would be to evaluate the [factorial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial): you may find this [se] discussion helpful: [Recursive function in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682524/recursive-function-in-bash)

Answer (score 4):

Shell itself does have a utility for generating various combinations. I am not quite sure of the technical term for this, but here's how it works:

```
$ echo {1,2,3}{1,2,3}{1,2,3}                                
111 112 113 121 122 123 131 132 133 211 212 213 221 222 223 231 232 233 311 312 313 321 322 323 331 332 333

$ echo {a,b,c}{a,b,c}{a,b,c}                                
aaa aab aac aba abb abc aca acb acc baa bab bac bba bbb bbc bca bcb bcc caa cab cac cba cbb cbc cca ccb ccc

$ echo {0,1}{0,1}{0,1}{0,1}
0000 0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 1010 1011 1100 1101 1110 1111
```

It's not ideal though, if I remember correctly, i was trying to generate a list of Ukrainian phone numbers (for science purposes, of course), and  ended up with errors. So shell has it's limits. A tool written in a particular programming language, might be of a better use.

Comment: Good enough since it is easy to understand. And as an extra pro-tip: this can be used with "mkdir" and "touch" too to create a whole lot of directories and files.

Comment: @Rinzwind Yup, very useful when you need to generate a ton of files for testing renaming scripts :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any great command line tools for this, but you can write one easily using python's included itertools library. For example, I just wrote up this script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2

"""
Script based in part on StackOverflow answer at:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434070/generating-all-combinations-of-a-list-in-python
"""

import sys
import itertools

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print 'No arguments provided; exiting.'
    sys.exit()

args = sys.argv[1:]
count = 0

for combolength in range(0, len(args) + 1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(args, combolength):
        print '#' + str(count) + ': ' + ' '.join(subset)
        count += 1
```

Assuming you have python2.3+ installed, you can paste that script into a file called 'combinations.py' and then run this command in a terminal while in the containing directory:

```
python combinations.py arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 arg5
```

It will accept any number of arguments.

So for example, if I want all combinations of the numbers 1, 2, 3 and 4, I can run:

```
python combinations.py 1 2 3 4
```

And I'll get:

```
#0: 
#1: 1
#2: 2
#3: 3
#4: 4
#5: 1 2
#6: 1 3
#7: 1 4
#8: 2 3
#9: 2 4
#10: 3 4
#11: 1 2 3
#12: 1 2 4
#13: 1 3 4
#14: 2 3 4
#15: 1 2 3 4
```

It doesn't need to be numbers. You can try:

```
python combinations.py pig cow duck
```

and get:

```
#0: 
#1: pig
#2: cow
#3: duck
#4: pig cow
#5: pig duck
#6: cow duck
#7: pig cow duck
```

Hope that helped!

P.S. If you're missing python for some reason, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

The default version should be fine.

Update: I made a couple small typos the first time so make sure you review my answer again if you were confused at first.

Comment: After working with your code, I found a way to use it for what I really wanted: permutations. However, they come out duplicated. Like if I give "permutations.py 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 2" etc, many entrees are: 000, 000, 000, 111, 111, 111, 222, 222, 222, etc. is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Yeah I made a few changes. This should work well for sets without much repetition; may be pretty slow for the example you gave, but I included percent done outputs through calculation so you know it's working. There might be a cleaner way but basically I just get the same output as the last example then prune out the repeats. I can basically guarantee there is a more efficient algorithm for this but this does get the job done.

http://hastebin.com/ivubunafug.py

Here's a diff if you want. https://www.diffchecker.com/nz70baya

Comment: Ben, the new program seems to place all combinations in memory before dumping the output on the screen. However, I want to use a combination that has about 10 million different results. Is there any way to modify the program to simply and immediately spit out the first number and THEN for every next number to check whether or not it is in the list already before proceeding?

Comment: I mean, it is checking for that. If you want to dig into the actual code for how it calculates combinations to try to cut that process short, you can, but that's considerably more complicated than what I wrote, I would assume.